# discord.js / typescript / heroku / github: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, github, heroku, import, discord.js

```
// imports all the things needed to run the discord bot successfully
import DiscordJS, { TextChannel, Intents, Message, Channel, NewsChannel, ThreadChannel, DiscordAPIError } from 'discord.js'
type guildTextBasedChannel = TextChannel | NewsChannel | ThreadChannel

import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

//sets prefix to be used when running bot commands
const prefix = '~';

//This lets the discord bot know what your intentions are using this bot. Hence the guilds, guilds messages and message reactions
const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
    ]
})

//This prints out "The bot is ready" whenever you turn the bot, hence the 'ready' parameter
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready')
})

//Allows the program to access the correct bot using the specified token
client.login(process.env.token)
```

I'm trying to make a discord bot but have it run 24/7 using github and heroku. I'm watching a video on how to set it up, but  I get an error when I run it on heroku.
[image: heroku error msg]

I'm guessing the error is because I'm using typescript for the bot. Do I have to convert to javascript or is there an easy fix?

EDIT:

```
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __setModuleDefault = (this && this.__setModuleDefault) || (Object.create ? (function(o, v) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, "default", { enumerable: true, value: v });
}) : function(o, v) {
    o["default"] = v;
});
var __importStar = (this && this.__importStar) || function (mod) {
    if (mod && mod.__esModule) return mod;
    var result = {};
    if (mod != null) for (var k in mod) if (k !== "default" && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mod, k)) __createBinding(result, mod, k);
    __setModuleDefault(result, mod);
    return result;
};
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });


// imports all the things needed to run the discord bot successfully
const discord_js_1 = __importStar(require("discord.js"));
const dotenv_1 = __importDefault(require("dotenv"));
dotenv_1.default.config();

//sets prefix to be used when running bot commands
const prefix = '~';

//This lets the discord bot know what your intentions are using this bot. Hence the guilds, guilds messages and message reactions
const client = new discord_js_1.default.Client({
    intents: [
        discord_js_1.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        discord_js_1.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        discord_js_1.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        discord_js_1.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
    ]
});




//This prints out "The bot is ready" whenever you turn the bot, hence the 'ready' parameter
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready');
});
client.login(process.env.token);
```

Above is index.js code after I did "tsc".
[image: error]

The above picture is the error message I got in heroku.

Comment: Make sure you're running the latest node version and `'type'` is set to `'module'` in your package.json (`'type': 'module',`)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Heroku, it doesn't work well if you're trying to execute the TS file directly. I recommend you use something like [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to transpile to JS and run the JavaScript on Heroku.

*Side note:* If you set `"type": "module"` in your package.json you will be unable to access some global variables such as `__dirname`

Comment: Hi, I used the tsc to transpile the code as you suggested, but theres another error saying that my token is invalid now which I'm not understanding, but I've updated the question with the index.js code and the error message. If you could help me again, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Did you use the --esModuleInterop flag? Also you might want to change `dotenv_1.default.config();` to `dotenv_1.config();`